# $\left \langle x,y\right\rangle\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ can be shown as $\bigcup_{i\in I}Q_i$ s.t. $Q_i$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, several-complex-variables

Prove that the ideal $\left \langle x,y\right\rangle\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ can be shown as $\bigcup_{i\in I}Q_i$ such that $Q_i$ is  a prime ideal.

Comment: $\Bbb C[x,y]$ is the polynomial ring with two indeterminates?

Comment: @Bernard Indeed.

Comment: Well, $\langle x,y\rangle$ itself is a maximal ideal.